# How can I get eclipse to compile java files in WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, eclipse

So heres the structure of my codebase.

```
ROOT DIR
    -- source dir 1
    -- source dir 2
    -- .
    -- .
    -- .
    -- WEB-INF
        -- classes
```

Under the java build path of my project I have added ROOT DIR. However it looks like the java files in WEB-INF/classes are not being compiled (most, if not all of my compile errors are because of these classes not being imported).

Apart from moving all those files in WEB-INF/classes to some other folder, is there some other solution to this?

Comment: If I don't missunderstand your problem is that your project isn't compiling the `sources dir *` isn't?, is it compiling only the default folder?. The folder `WEB-INF/classes` is only for compiled classes.

Comment: @maqjav - I have changed the sources in eclispe to include ROOT DIR. Yes i understand that WEB-INF/classes is for compiled classes but in this code that i have got, the sources are there in WEB-INF/classes. I don't want to move it around because it is under version control (SVN). I have changed the build/deployment directory to build/classes/ to avoid these conflicts.

Comment: Have a look at project properties, under 'Java Build Path', 'Source' tab. That is where this configuration is controlled from.

Comment: Why do you have Java _source_ in `WEB-INF/classes`?  That's where compiled `.class` files normally go.

Comment: this is some old code I'm on with files there.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at project properties, under 'Java Build Path', 'Source' tab. That is where this configuration is controlled from.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Configuration of the project, Select the Source tab, give the folder path for the classes in the Default output folder texbox

Comment: have already done that. the output folder is ROOTDIR/build/classes